# Properties of the solution of a differential equation with reversed input.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have two 2nd order systems.

**System 1:**
$$\ddot{\theta}_{1}(t) + \sin{\theta}_{1}(t) = \cos{\theta}_{1}(t)f(t), \text{ with } t \in [0, T],$$
and $\theta_{1}(0)=\dot{\theta}_{1}(0)=0$ and $\theta_{1}(T)=a,\: \dot{\theta}_{1}(T) = 0$.

**System 2:**
$$\ddot{\theta}_{2}(\mu) + \sin{\theta}_{2}(\mu) = \cos{\theta}_{2}(\mu)f(2T-\mu), \text{ with } \mu = t + T \in [T,2T],$$ 
and $\theta_{2}(T)= a, \: \dot{\theta}_{2}(T)=0,$ namely

- **System 2 is identical to System 1.**
- **The initial condition of the System 2 is the terminal condition of the System 1.**
- **The input of the System 2 is the reversed version of the System 1's input.**

Note that $f(t)$ is a real function, $T$ is a positive terminal time, and $a$ is a positive real number.

**My purpose is**: prove that $\theta_{2}(2T) = \dot{\theta}_{2}(2T) = 0$.

I very much appreciate any suggestion or hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second equation, set $s=2T-μ$, $y(s)=θ_2(μ)$, then the second equation reads as
$$
\ddot y(s)+\sin(y(s))=\cos(y(s))f(s), ~~ s\in[0,T],\\~\\
y(T)=a,~\dot y(T)=0.
$$
This is exactly identical to the first equation with the same boundary conditions at $T$, $y(T)=θ_1(T)$, $\dot y(T)=\dot θ_1(T)$. Since these are complete as initial conditions, there is only one solution to the resulting IVP, thus $y(s)=θ_1(s)$ for all $s\in[0,T]$, and so you get also the same values at $s=0$ which translate as values for $θ_2$ at $s=2T$.

---

Note that the original system for $θ_1$ is overdetermined, resp. that $f$ has to be chosen correctly so that all 3 homogeneous boundary conditions are satisfied simultaneously. With a general $f$ the problem for $θ_1$ is usually not solvable.

Comment: Thanks @LutzL! At first, I also thought in the same direction with your answer but I am afraid that it is wrong. With $s = 2T - \mu$ and $\mu \in [T, 2T]$, we have $s \in [T, 0]$, namely $s$ will go from $T$ to $0$. So, $y(T) = a$ and $\dot{y}(T) = 0$ are the **initial condition** for the $y(s)$ system, not terminal condition. Obviously, the initial condition $y(T) = a, \: \dot{y}(T) = 0$ is different from that of the System 1 ($\theta_{1}(0) = \dot{\theta}_{1}(0) = 0$). Therefore, we cannot conclude $y(s) = \theta_{1}(s)$ except in the case that $a = 0$. Do you have any further idea? Thanks!

Comment: "Initial condition" does not mean that you are only allowed to integrate forward. The maximal domain $(\alpha,\beta)$ has usually the initial time well inside.

Comment: Thanks! According to your proof, does the result hold when we change the terminal condition of the System 1 from $\theta_{1}(T) = a, \dot{\theta}_{1}(T) = 0$ to $\theta_{1}(T) = a, \dot{\theta}_{1}(T) = b$, where $b \neq 0$?

Comment: No, as $\dot y(s)=-\dot θ_2(μ)$, you would not get a differentiable continuation, the right side for the full function would have a Dirac-delta term. If the function is even symmetric at $T$, then the derivative there must be zero.

Comment: Oh, the point I missed is the continuity condition for the solution, which indeed result in $b = 0$. Thanks a lot!